# Using `map` to write lines to files

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of lines:

```
lines = [a,b,c,d]
```

And a list of files (created via `open(path string,'w')`:

```
files = [e,f,g,h]
```

What I am trying to do is write each line to its respective file (line `a` should go with file `e` and a new line). Note, this is all part of a much larger loop to generate the lines and put them in this list of lines you see:

This is my current method:

```
map(lambda (x,y): y.write(x) + "\n",zip(lines,files))
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

What is a way of achieving what I need? Writing each line to each file separately is very cumbersome.

Comment: map is a transformational method... Why not use a regular for loop? Your problem is that the write method returns None and you added a newline to that instead of `x`

Comment: That is a terrible idea and would not write at all using Python 3 even if you got it working with calling list on the map object, your approach would also be way slower than just using a regular for loop

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this?

Comment: @Dhruv, probably because it is a typographical error that you should have been able to figure out yourself.

Comment: A typographical error would be `labmda`, not attempting to add two incompatible types.

Comment: @chepner, the newline should have been inside the paren, looks like a typo to me, regardless a pretty simple thing to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean to do:

```
map(lambda (x,y): y.write(x + "\n"), zip(lines,files))
```

But I'd rather do it as:

```
for l, f in zip(lines,files):
    f.write(l + "\n")
```

Comment: To emphasize: don't use `map` if you aren't planning to use the list value it returns.